# Need to have console output stored in a database table

Tags: java, sql-server, zip

I created a code that counts the number of files in a zipfile. I am currently outputting the information onto the console. I am not sure how to get started in putting the outputted information into a database table in Microsoft SQL server. I essentially just need to have it output to a table in Microsoft SQL server instead of outputting it to the console. I have the code below:

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.PrintStream;

import java.nio.file.Files;

import java.nio.file.Path;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

import java.util.Enumeration;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;

import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

 

public class KZF

{

    static int findNumberOfFiles(File file) {

        try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file)) {

            return (int) zipFile.stream().filter(z -> !z.isDirectory()).count();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            return -1;

        }

    }

 

    static String createInfo(File file) {

        int tot = findNumberOfFiles(file) - 1;

        return (file.getName() + ": " + (tot >= 0 ? tot + " files" : "Error reading zip file"));

    }

 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String dirLocation = "C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Temp\\AllKo";

        try (Stream<Path> files = Files.list(Paths.get(dirLocation))) {

            files

            .filter(path -> path.toFile().isFile())

            .filter(path -> path.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".zip"))

            .map(Path::toFile)

            .map(KZF::createInfo)

            .forEach(System.out::println);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To interact with SQL-based databases in java, the 'base layer' is a library called JDBC. This works as follows:

1. JDBC itself is part of plain java just as much as `java.io.File` is. However, this is just the basic API you use to interact with Databases, it doesn't include support for any specific database. [Here is the API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/package-summary.html).
2. You then need a so-called JDBC Driver; you'd need the [JDBC driver for Microsoft SQL server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). This driver needs to be on the classpath when you run your app; you don't need to reference any particular class file or 'load' it, just... make sure it's on the classpath, that's all you need. This jar, if on the classpath, automatically tells the JDBC system about its existence, and the JDBC system will then use it when you ask the JDBC system to connect to your microsoft sql database. Hence, nothing required except for this to be present on the classpath.
3. JDBC is intentionally a convoluted and hard to use API from the point of view of interacting with DBs from plain jane java code: It's the lowest denominator; the 'machine code' aspect. It needs to expose all possible DB functionality for all possible SQL-based database engines and give you the tools to run it in all possible modes. Thus, I strongly advise you *not* to program direct JDBC. Instead, use libraries that are built on top of JDBC and give you a nice, easy to understand API: Use [JDBI](https://www.jdbi.org) or [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/), but I believe JOOQ is not free unless you use it with a free DB, and microsoft SQL isn't free, so be aware you may need to pay a license fee for JOOQ. JDBI is free.

In other words:

- in your build system, add the [`com.microsoft.sqlserver :: mssql-jdbc :: 9.2.1.jre11`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/9.2.1.jre11) dependency.
- in your build system, add the [`org.jdbi :: jdbi3-core :: 3.20.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdbi/jdbi3-core/3.20.0) dependency.
- Read the [Microsoft SQL Server JDBC connector URL docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver15) on how to build the so-called 'JDBC URL' which tells java how to connect to your microsoft SQL server.
- Read the [JDBI documentation](https://jdbi.org). It's not hard - right on the front page you see the basic layout for how to send INSERT statements. (the URL you learned about in the previous doc? You pass that to the `Jdbi.create()` call).

Answer (score -1):

Much easier, you can use the entries() method to get an Enumeration of the ZipEntry-s in the zip-file, and check each one to see if it isDirectory():

```
int countRegularFiles(final ZipFile zipFile) {
    final Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
    int numRegularFiles = 0;
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        if (! entries.nextElement().isDirectory()) {
            ++numRegularFiles;
        }
    }
    return numRegularFiles;
}
```

Comment: The question asks about how to interact with databased from java, and pasted some code to clarify the question. An answer is probably not the best place for an unrelated comment on code quality, especially this one which doesn't seem to be an improvement.